# is URDF model needed for ros control?

Tags: ros, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, It's first time to use ros control, and there's a confusing question.

In my project, I need to navigate a mobile robot (double steering type) to the target place. For navigation algorithm, maybe TEB or DWA will be used (both publish cmd_vel), and I think this won't be a problem for me. So the next thing to do is to construct the ROS control framework.

Follow the ros wiki, I can understand the framework. I need to write a robotHW by myself to Read/Write hardware data and transmit to ros controller. So the whole framework is that:

Navigation algorithms <---pub, sub data---> ros controller

ros controller <--- transmit ---> robotHW

robotHW <--- Read/Write ---> hardware

is it right? If yes, there's no URDF model included, so it is not necessary for the ros control.
If not, there's something I missed or I misunderstood?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397330/is-urdf-model-needed-for-ros-control?/) by [RyanChen.YLC](https://answers.ros.org/users/99089/ryanchen.ylc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2022-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A URDF is not strictly required, however many controller implementations will want to take a look at a URDF to determine/derive some properties of your robot.

The `DiffDriveController` would be one of those controllers.

If however, you don't use any of those controllers, and you write your `RobotHW` such that it doesn't rely on a URDF for information about the structure of your robot (ie: nr of joints, their type, etc), then: no, a URDF would not be required.

Note that many other parts of ROS will want/need a URDF though (such as RViz and the `robot_state_publisher`), so it would still be a good idea to have/make one.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1